# Taylor Expansion of $\log \left( 1+\frac{4.645}{\sqrt{R\cdot S}} \right)$

Tags: taylor-expansion

I've come across the following Taylor expansion in an old hydraulics paper
$$
\log \left( 1+\frac{4.645}{\sqrt{R\cdot S}} \right)=\frac{1}{2.303}\left( x-\frac{{{x}^{2}}}{2}+\frac{{{x}^{3}}}{3}\ldots etc. \right)
$$
where x is
$$
x=\frac{4.645}{\sqrt{R\cdot S}}
$$
I can see that the Taylor Expansion of $\log \left( 1+x \right)=\left( x-\frac{{{x}^{2}}}{2}+\frac{{{x}^{3}}}{3}\ldots etc. \right)$ so where does the $\frac{1}{2.303}$ come from.
I can see it is $\frac{1}{\ln \left( 10 \right)}=\frac{1}{2.303}$, but why?
Thanks in advance

Comment: the old papers meant log to be in base 10 and ln to be in base e.

Comment: Yes, I thought of that, but I still unfortunately can't seem to get my head around where the 1/2.303 comes from

Comment: Here's a link that may help: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_logarithmic_identities#Changing_the_base